# Reporting Services Error on First Run of any Report

Tags: authentication, reporting-services, forms-authentication, ssrs-2008

This is a strange one!

We have a forms authentication module implemented and is all working fine.

However, when you restart/first run reporting services, the first report to run returns an Error 500, Internal Server Error. If you then re-run the report, all works perfectly well, and all reports work perfectly well from this point.

It's not the report, it happens on a simple 'blank' report.

The Reporting Service Log file shows a 'file not exists error', but not which file.

```
webserver!ReportServer_0-2!266c!08/22/2011-14:32:09:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.UnhandledHttpApplicationException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.UnhandledHttpApplicationException: The report server encountered an unhandled exception in HttpApplication. --->
```

**System.Web.HttpException: File does not exist.**

```
   at System.Web.StaticFileHandler.GetFileInfo(String virtualPathWithPathInfo, String physicalPath, HttpResponse response)
   at System.Web.StaticFileHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---;
ui!ReportManager_0-1!26cc!08/22/2011-14:32:09:: e ERROR:
```

**System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.**

```
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.ServerAuthType.GetReportServerAuthentication()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.ServerAuthType.get_ServerUsesBasic()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.WebControlConnection.get_NetworkCredentials()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.get_ServerNetworkCredentials()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.get_Service()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.GetServerVersion()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.ViewReport.Control_Init(Object sender, EventArgs args)
   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnInit(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.AddedControl(Control control, Int32 index)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.SharedArea.Control_Init(Object sender, EventArgs args)
   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnInit(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.AddedControl(Control control, Int32 index)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.ReportWrapperPage.Page_Init(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnInit(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.OnInit(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
ui!ReportManager_0-1!26cc!08/22/2011-14:32:09:: e ERROR: HTTP status code --> 500
-------Details--------


**System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.**



   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.ServerAuthType.GetReportServerAuthentication()

   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.ServerAuthType.get_ServerUsesBasic()

   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.WebControlConnection.get_NetworkCredentials()

   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.get_ServerNetworkCredentials()

   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.get_Service()

   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.GetServerVersion()

   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.ViewReport.Control_Init(Object sender, EventArgs args)

   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)

   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnInit(EventArgs e)

   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)

   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)

   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)

   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)

   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)

   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)

   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)

   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)

   at System.Web.UI.Control.AddedControl(Control control, Int32 index)

   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.SharedArea.Control_Init(Object sender, EventArgs args)

   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)

   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnInit(EventArgs e)

   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)

   at System.Web.UI.Control.AddedControl(Control control, Int32 index)

   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.ReportWrapperPage.Page_Init(Object sender, EventArgs e)

   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)

   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnInit(EventArgs e)

   at System.Web.UI.Page.OnInit(EventArgs e)

   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)

   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
library!ReportServer_0-2!25d8!08/22/2011-14:32:09:: Call to GetSystemPropertiesAction().
ui!ReportManager_0-1!26cc!08/22/2011-14:32:09:: e ERROR:
```

**System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.**

```
   at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()
   at System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.End()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.ReportingPage.ShowErrorPage(String errMsg)
```

***Any*** help/hints/suggestions much appreciated, as I've ran out of them!

I'm pretty sure it's an authentication issue. A report can have a subscription 'cache' refresh and still work, but then you still get the above the first time a 'user' tries to run any report.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this?

Comment: No! Fortunately when you just run a report from a url, that's ok, but from the iframe it's not. Only 2 people actually see this problem, they are living with it, but it still annoys me!

Comment: As far I debug into this behaviour I see that it is related to the Logon.aspx.cs. This page is called on the very first time. In my case I checked Request.Url.Host and it was 127.0.0.1 in result which is caused by the settings on my UI - ReportServerUrl in rsreportserverconfig.xml. But I still face the same problem and still investigate what is causes.

Comment: Don't you hate when you find someone with the same problem without a fix? :) Same here ...

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where it would load the first report but did not reload other reports when selecting from the my custom dropdownlist. so the window did not refresh with new data. I had to do the following to get it working. Hope this gives you some ideas.

```
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Dispose();

ReportViewer1.Reset();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Perhaps that's part of the problem, we are not using the report control, just an IFrame to the report server etc.